# Can't publish VS Code extension anymore after `npm update`?

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I just can't publish my extension anymore.
It just worked fine before I ran `npm update`.

Now it says all day, no matter what:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "vscode:prepublish"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! eppz-code@1.1.25 vscode:prepublish: `tsc -p ./`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the eppz-code@1.1.25 vscode:prepublish script 'tsc -p ./'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
```

See dependencies in [**`package.json`**](https://github.com/eppz/VSCode.Extension.eppz_Code/blob/master/package.json) to get the full picture.

I tried with countless node versions (6.x to 7.x), no luck with any.
**Anyone with similar issues** ended up in a solution?

Comment: Extremely annoying, I removed almost everything from the extension, still no results...

Comment: tried updating your ts?

Comment: Thanks for getting back, updated to `2.2.2` still same symptoms. Having the latest `node.js` and `npm` did not helped neither. That was my first attempt.

Comment: Apparently you've a problem on this line `"vscode:prepublish": "tsc -p ./",`
Try `"vscode:prepublish": "tsc"` instead. Not sure.

Comment: Well, this is the official vs code boilerplate script before prepublish (see [**`package.json#140`**](https://github.com/eppz/VSCode.Extension.eppz_Code/blob/master/package.json#L140)). I don't think it should be tweaked locally. I also want the extension to work after I publish it. :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Manually deleting entire `node_modules` content, then reinstall everything (with `npm install`) simply solved the issue.